# How to import sails.js disk.db to mongodb

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

So I have a nodejs app that is using [sailsjs](http://sailsjs.org/) web framework. While Im developing, I have the adapter set to sails-disk. Sample data from `disk.db` is like

```
{
    "data": {
        "authentication": [
            {
                "user_id": 1,
                "username": "user1",
                "encrypted_password": "password here",
                "createdAt": "2014-05-12T07:40:24.901Z",
                "updatedAt": "2014-08-18T19:37:22.851Z",
                "id": 1,
                "email": "user1@email.com"
            }
        ],
        "user": [
            {
                "name": "user0001",
                "email": "user1@email.com",
                "role": [
                    "admin"
                ],
                "phone": [
                    {}
                ],
                "status": "Active",
                "createdAt": "2014-05-12T07:48:11.028Z",
                "updatedAt": "2014-05-24T08:12:41.646Z",
                "id": 1,
                "username": "user1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This works perfectly on my local machine.
Now, I'm ready to deploy it on production and use mongodb as my database. I have all the connections setup and I can successfully connect on my db.

My question is: Is there a way that I can import my local disk database (`disk.db`) to mongodb while maintaing my json data format or collections? Or I need to create my collections on mongodb manually and import each collection?

Comment: Are you concerned about migrating actual data records, or just collections?  MongoDB will create the collections for you as they are needed, so you don't need to do anything if that's all you want to happen.

Comment: Yes- the actual data records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no tool or official way to do this kind of migration with Sails.  Depending on how many models you have and how tedious it would be to write a script to migrate things for you, one option is to mirror your models--that is, if you have a `User.js`, make a new model `UserNew.js` that looks like:

```
module.exports = {

    connection: 'mongoDbConnection',
    tableName: 'user',
    attributes: <same as User.js attributes>

}
```

and then in your **config/bootstrap.js** do:

```
User.find().exec(function(err, users) {
    UserNew.create(users).exec(...);
}
```

to transfer them over.

This would be a one-time thing after which you could drop your original `User.js` and rename `UserNew.js` to `User.js`.  Pretty hacky, but again depending on how much data we're talking about, it might be the quickest option!

Answer (score 0):

I built on the answer from sgress454 and flipped it around. Instead of a NewUser I created a OldUserLocation.js model.

```
module.exports = {
    connection: 'localDiskDb',
    tableName: 'user',
    attributes: {
    //same as in User.js
}
```

}

And in the default model I specified mongo DB.

In the bootstrap function I added this:

```
User.find().exec(function(err, users){
    if(!err && users.length == 0){
        OldUserLocation.find().exec(function(err, oldUsers) {
            if(!err && oldUsers.length >0){
                User.create(oldUsers).exec(function (err){
                    cb();
                });
            }
            else{
                cb();
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        cb();  
    } 
});
```

Simply put, if the user model in the mongo DB has no users then I try and import from the localdisk db. If it already has users I assume the import is done already.

Answer (score 0):

Another hacky way I see is :

- open `.tmp/localDiskDb.db`
- copy a an object
- run a POST query using
  Postman https://www.getpostman.com/apps
- set the query to POST
- set the endpoint URL in the "body" tab choose 'raw', 'JSON' paste the object in the box
- press send

rince, repeat